# Attempting a "minimum viable" SharpDX 12 setup; error 0x887A0005 "device removed"

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, sharpdx, directx-12

The goal: Write "minimum viable", no frills or extras code that sets up SharpDX 12 (a C# wrapper around DirectX 12), creates a window, and executes a present loop that clears the screen to RGBA (0, 0, 1, 1).

The expectation: Having followed a DirectX 12 setup tutorial as best as I can, I would then get a window with a blue background.

The outcome: On the **second** run through the loop, on the line "swapChain.Present(1, SharpDX.DXGI.PresentFlags.None);" The error message "SharpDX.SharpDXException: HRESULT: [0x887A0005], Module: [SharpDX.DXGI], ApiCode: [DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED/DeviceRemoved], Message: The GPU device instance has been suspended. Use GetDeviceRemovedReason to determine the appropriate action.

at SharpDX.Result.CheckError()
   at SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain.Present(Int32 syncInterval, PresentFlags flags)
   at DirectX12BlueScreen.Program.Main(String[] args) in *\DirectX12BlueScreen\DirectX12BlueScreen\Program.cs:line 114" printed to the console window (which I am using for debug output)

What I am looking for: Why the error is happening (the device has certainly not been removed); what part of my code is causing the error; and a solution to the problem, if the preceding two pieces of information do not supply that information.

As the full code is 165 lines, I have posted the loop here, and the full code in a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/vctaYkNC

```
while(form.Visible)
{
    commandAllocator[0].Reset();
    commandList.Reset(commandAllocator[0], null);
    commandList.SetViewport(viewport: viewport);
    commandList.SetScissorRectangles(rectangle: scissorsRectangle);
    commandList.ResourceBarrierTransition(
        resource: renderTargets[0],
        stateBefore: ResourceStates.Present,
        stateAfter: ResourceStates.RenderTarget);
    commandList.ClearRenderTargetView(
        renderTargetView:
        rtvDescriptorHeap.CPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart,
        colorRGBA: new RawColor4(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));
    commandList.ResourceBarrierTransition(
        resource: renderTargets[0],
        stateBefore: ResourceStates.RenderTarget,
        stateAfter: ResourceStates.Present);
    commandList.Close();
    commandQueue.ExecuteCommandList(commandList);
    swapChain.Present(1, SharpDX.DXGI.PresentFlags.None);
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Edit: Using information supplied by PhillipH, I now have a more accurate error readout:
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
   at SharpDX.Direct3D12.GraphicsCommandList.ClearRenderTargetView(CpuDescriptorHandle renderTargetView, RawColor4 colorRGBA, Int32 numRects, RawRectangle[] rectsRef)
   at SharpDX.Direct3D12.GraphicsCommandList.ClearRenderTargetView(CpuDescriptorHandle renderTargetView, RawColor4 colorRGBA)
   at DirectX12BlueScreen.Program.Main(String[] args) in *\DirectX12BlueScreen\DirectX12BlueScreen\Program.cs:line 138"

Comment: Did you "Use GetDeviceRemovedReason to determine the appropriate action" ? The DeviceRemoved occurs when you force DirectX to remove the device from you - not neccessarily because of any external factor. 

Its really vital you set up your debugging correctly for SharpDX - you must Enable Native Code Debugging, you must create your device with new Device(adapter, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug). If you take those two steps all internal errors will be fully described to you in the Output window of Visual Studio.

Comment: All I am able to specify for new Device() is adapter and minimum feature level.

Comment: Sorry - I dont understand your query on my comment.

Comment: I can't specify DeviceCreationFlags in my "new Device()" call because the constructor only has parameters for, at most, an adapter and a minimum feature level. There is no constructor for Device that takes DeviceCreationFlags.

Comment: Looking at the source code for SharpDX, there should be; but I'm not seeing it in Visual Studio. I'm going to try making a new project with the exact same code, and see if that fixes it. This code was originally written for an older version of SharpDX 12, and then we moved houses. It is using 4.0.1 now, but some remnant might be interfering.

Comment: Didn't work. The new project shows the exact same parameters; no DeviceCreationFlags parameter. This is...Odd.

Comment: Ah; Google brought me to the SharpDX11 Device.cs file. Looking in the right SharpDX12 Device file, it does *Not* have a DeviceCreationFlags parameter: https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Direct3D12/Device.cs

Comment: Hmm, what was the last release date of SharpDX ? I only ever used SharpDX11 so this is why I get a different signature to you.

Comment: "(Last Update: 29 May 2017, release notes for 4.0.0)". The latest version on NuGet is 4.0.1. I'm going to try going back down a tiny notch to 4.0.0. ...No change to "new Device()" parameters. There is a DebugDevice, but that only takes an IntPtr parameter. And StackOverflow is asking about moving this dicussion to chat.

Comment: The normal practise is to 'Device device = new Device(adapter, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug);' and then 'DeviceDebug debugDevice = new DeviceDebug(device);' - the debugDevice is used to interrogate for object life histories and isn't important in your context. Looks like Dx12 has a different method of pumping out debug message to Dx11.

Comment: Maybe this is now all controlled from the DX control panel as suggested here https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/issues/99

Comment: Enabling Debug layer in Direct3D12 is done differently from Direct3D11

You need to call: SharpDX.Direct3D12.DebugInterface.Get().EnableDebugLayer();

This should be done before to create the Direct3D12 device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not setting up the render targets correctly, and I wasn't using fences at all. I was using SwapChain rather than SwapChain3, and so couldn't get the current buffer index. The correct code has been put into a pastebin for future reference.

It successfully rendered as intended for three minutes, so I think I can call this one resolved.

Thanks to PhillipH, without whose help I'd still be wondering how to get good error messages.

https://pastebin.com/Ku7wqHpJ

The working render loop:

```
while (form.Visible)
{
    commandAllocator[0].Reset();
    commandList.Reset(commandAllocator[0], null);
    commandList.ResourceBarrierTransition(
        resource: renderTargets[currentBufferIndex],
        stateBefore: ResourceStates.Present,
        stateAfter: ResourceStates.RenderTarget);
    renderTargetView =
        rtvDescriptorHeap.CPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart +
        currentBufferIndex *
        renderTargetViewHeapSize;
    commandList.ClearRenderTargetView(
        renderTargetView: renderTargetView,
        colorRGBA: new RawColor4(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));
    commandList.ResourceBarrierTransition(
        resource: renderTargets[currentBufferIndex],
        stateBefore: ResourceStates.RenderTarget,
        stateAfter: ResourceStates.Present);
    commandList.Close();
    commandQueue.ExecuteCommandList(commandList);
    swapChain.Present(1, SharpDX.DXGI.PresentFlags.None);
    long fenceToWaitFor = fenceValue;
    commandQueue.Signal(fence[0], fenceValue);
    ++fenceValue;
    if (fence[0].CompletedValue < fenceValue)
    {
        fence[0].SetEventOnCompletion(fenceToWaitFor,
            fenceEvent.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
        fenceEvent.WaitOne();
        fenceEvent.Reset();
    }

    currentBufferIndex = swapChain.CurrentBackBufferIndex;
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```